# Safe way to backup env.yml - Serverless Framework

Tags: security, serverless-framework

It's best practice to put sensitive environment variables into env.yml and reference them in serverless.yml. Of course, this also means not checking env.yml into a code repository.

So where's a safe place to store a backup of env.yml? We have a number of microservices, so we're accumulating several env.yml files for our projects. Even sharing them among devs and keeping them updated can become a bit of an issue - they really could benefit from version control but security trumps convenience so we keep them out of git.

I'd be interested to hear how others manage secrets config in general.

Comment: See https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-secrets-api-keys/

Comment: Thank you @Alex! The AWS Parameter Store looks like a real possibility for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the question was specifically about management of env.yml files, the bigger underlying question is how to manage sensitive environment variables. The link in the comment from Alex is all I needed. Our solution is so AWS-oriented that the AWS Parameter Store is worth exploring.

[Alex DeBrie's article](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-secrets-api-keys/)

[Yan Cui's article on referencing parameter store values at runtime](https://hackernoon.com/you-should-use-ssm-parameter-store-over-lambda-env-variables-5197fc6ea45b)